# How to use Tiled Editor to recreate a 2D map?

Tags: 2d, tiled, importing

Alright, to familiarize ourselves with the Tiled Editor, the teacher asked us to replicate a tile-based map of a 2D platformer.

*He gave us pretty much these two things:*

**1.) A selection of maps to copy from (Choose one map to copy)**

**2.) A folder with subfolders that contains 16x16 images on each subfolder (tiles)**

Naturally, I started by importing the images from the folders by clicking on each folder, and importing each collection, which takes a long amount of time..(also considering the tiles for the other maps are mixed in here as well)

I used the png image as a transparent backdrop to help me place the tiles, then started placing tiles, which again, took a lot of time...

More than halfway there, I realized the width I set the map when I created it wasn't enough and tried to change the option under properties but it was grayed out. I also tried creating a new map and copying and pasting from my original one but that one doesn't seem to work either.

Is there a way to speed up the process a little bit? or salvage the tmx file?
Considering that he might ask us to create more maps later on, I'd like to be a bit informed...

---

I've also looked up the possibility of importing the image itself, slicing it to the desired tile size and removing duplicate tiles. This way I can simply import the map png and have the software only create tiles that are used in the level.

Can this be done?

Comment: To re-size an existing map, don't use the property grid (as you've noticed you can't), use the re-size option under the Map menu. It will also allow you to pick an anchor point so that the "new" area of the map extends in the direction you want.

Comment: @bornander You should post this as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Philipp My comment doesn't really address the whole question, that's why I opted for a comment. Ideally the question would be split into two, one for re-sizing and one for how to handle tiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About resizing, as @bornander commented, there's a menu action for resizing that you need to use rather than directly changing the size in the Properties view.

---

The following article is about automating the process of creating a tile map and a tileset based on an image of a map: https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/wiki/Import-from-Image

As of now, Tiled can't do this natively, but it's something I'd like to add support for eventually.